# IBM Websphere scripting ID 'containment paths' explained (I.e. AdminConfig.getid(...) )

Tags: configuration, scripting, websphere, jython

I have been digging through IBM knowledge center and have returned frustrated at the lack of definition to some of their scripting interfaces.

IBM keeps talking about a *[containment path](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/txml_specifyconfig.html?lang=en)* used in their id definitions and I am only assuming that it corresponds to an xml element within file in the websphere config folder hierachy, but that's only from observation. I haven't found this declared in any documentation as yet.

Also, to find an ID, there is a syntax that needs to be used that will retrieve it, yet I cannot find a reference to the possible values of 'types' used in the `AdminConfig.getid(...)` function call.

So to summarize I have a couple questions:

1. **What is the correct definition of the id "heirachy" both for fetching an id and for the id itself?**

   > e.g. to get an Id of the server I would say something like: `AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:MYCOMPUTERNode01Cell/Node:MYCOMPUTERNode01/Server:server1')`, which would give me an id something like: `server1(cells/MYCOMPUTERNode01Cell/nodes/MYCOMPUTERNode01/servers/server1|server.xml#server_1873491723429)`
2. **What are the possible `/type` values in retrieving the id from the websphere server?**

   > e.g. in the above example, /Cell, /Node and /Server are examples of type values used in queries.

**UPDATE:** I have discovered [this document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rcfg_rconfdoc_descriptions.html?cp=SSAW57_8.0.0%2F1-16-4-9&lang=en) that outlines the locations of various configuration files in the configuration directory.

**UPDATE:** I am starting to think that the configuration files represent complex objects with attributes and nested attributes. not every object with an 'id' is query-able through the `AdminConfig.getid(<containment_path>)`. Object attributes (and this is not attributes in the strict xml sense as 'attributes' could be nested nodes with a simple structure within the parent node) may be queried using `AdminConfig.showAttribute(<element_id>, <attribute_name>)`. This function will either return the string value of the inline attribute of the element itself or a string list representation of the ids of the nested attribute node(s).

**UPDATE:** I have discovered the `AdminConfig.types()` function that will display a list of all manipulatible object types in the configuration files and the `AdminConfig.parent()` function that displays what nodes are considered parents of the specified node.

> *Note:* The `AdminConfig.parent()` function does not reveal the parents in order of their hierachy, rather it seems to just present a list of parents. e.g. `AdminConfig.parent('JDBCProvider')` gives us this exact list: `'Cell\nDeployment\nNode\nServer\nServerCluster'` and even though `Server` comes before `ServerCluster` , running `AdminConfig.parent('Server')` reveals it's parents as: `'Node\nServerCluster'`. Although some elements can have no parents - e.g. `Cell` - Some elements produce an error when running the `parent` function - e.g. `Deployment`.
>
> Due to the apparent lack of a reciprocal `AdminConfig.children()` function, It appears as though obtaining a full hierachical tree of parents/children lies in calling this function on each of the elements returned from the `AdminConfig.parent(<>)` call and combining the results. That being said, a trial and error approach is mostly fruitful due to the sometimes obvious ordering.